# Creating a function that returns a number from -10 to 10 based on mouseX position between 0 and 1920?

Tags: javascript

I remember seeing a function that did exactly that a long time ago but now that I need it, I can't find it. Essentially I am trying to make a function that would return a number from -10 to 10 based on mouseX position between 0 and 1920. The number can be a float like 4.3. Some examples:

- If mouseX is 0 the function would return -10
- if mouseX is 480 the function would return -5
- if mouseX is 960 the function would return 0
- if mouseX is 1920 the function would return 10
- if mouseX is 1638 the function do the calculation and return a number in the 5 to 10 range ( I'm not sure which one it would be, maybe 7.5 - 8.7 )

How can I make such a function? Sadly I'm having some trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Sounds like a [linear equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function_(calculus)): `x => x * 20 / 1920 - 10`

Comment: For 1638 do you want the output as 7.0625? Because 20 * (1638 / 1920) - 10 = 7.0625

Comment: Oh that's equation did work out! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function which calculates the new values.

```js
const
    takeRange = (smin, smax, tmin, tmax) => x => ((x - smin) * (tmax - tmin) / (smax - smin)) + tmin;
    fn = takeRange(0, 1920, -10, 10);

console.log(fn(0));    // -10
console.log(fn(480));  //  -5
console.log(fn(960));  //   0
console.log(fn(1920)); //  10
console.log(fn(1638)); //   7.0625
```